# Android SDK 20 update breaks graphical layout in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

It is really strange, but since the update to SDK version 20, the graphical layouts are not working anymore in Eclipse. They only display as a bunch of 'labels' of the components/widgets used.

I tried the tips I read on Stackoverflow to fix that (right-clicking the XML file and selecting "Graphical Editor", ensuring my XML file has an XML extension, changing the API version, changing Build Target, Clean Project etc., but it's all the same.

I even just spent almost 1 hour to uninstall and then reinstall the Android SDK - without suçcess.

Any idea how to get my Graphical layouts back?

**EDIT:**  I found out that the problem is caused by defining my own 'view'.

```
        <view
            android:id="@+id/vs_mapview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            class="com.mytest.TapControlledMapView"
            android:apiKey="0eaQ..."
            android:clickable="true"
            android:state_enabled="true" />
```

It worked fine with the previous ADT plugin, but since the update graphical display is broken wherever I use this snippet of code...

Comment: right click and select android layout editor and update your ADT plugin also if you are using new sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete any custom device screen configuration you have added . It will solve the issue :)

Comment: hmm.. I'm using an original Eclipse installation, I don't recall changing anything. Do you mean the screen configuration in the Emulator? Bcoz my problem is in the graphical layout editor in Eclipse, not the Emulator.

Comment: @user1229940, this actually solved the problem ! 10x (need to be marked as the answer !)

Comment: I was having this issue and saw the following exception in the eclipse log file `!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2012-07-17 11:22:49.069
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.configuration.ConfigurationComposite.computeCurrentConfig(ConfigurationComposite.java:2866)....`  Sure enough, I had an old Custom screen configuration defined in Eclipse and, once deleted, everything works fine now!

Comment: Would be nice addition to add how to delete custom device configuration.

Answer (score 2):

on the right where the little android man is swap it to an older version (try 13) that fixed it for me